# Why the useEffect hook does not work with state variable in context?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My code is [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wuwed5?file=src/QQTableBody.js).

I expect the content of the array `testingData` should be shown.

However, it does not be shown.

When I remove the `useEffect` hook, it works.

Would you tell me why and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In react, a component only renders if there are any state or prop changes. In your codebase `rowList` is a variable instead of a state. if you convert it to state, it should work.

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import WebContext from "./WebContext";
export default function QQTableBody(props) {
  let { testingData, setTestingData } = useContext(WebContext);
  const [rowList, setRowList] = useState([]);
  // let rowList=[];
  useEffect(() => {
    const list = [];
    testingData.forEach(data => {
      list.push(
        <tr>
         <td>{data}</td>
        </tr>
     );
   });
    setRowList(list);
   }, [testingData]);
 
   return <tbody>{rowList}</tbody>;
}
```